# Why is my image not showing up in my Windows Phone App?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I want to add an image to one of my pages within my app. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and coding in VB.NET, and to add an image first i insert an image control onto the page, then i select the source which is the image that i want to insert, i then set the images build action to'content' and build the program but the image does not appear as visible?

Does anybody know why it is doing this?

My XML code is the following:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="RSG_Engineer.MainPage"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" OpacityMask="{x:Null}">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Height="133" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="Rectangle1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Fill="#FF00B1FF" />
    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="RSG Engineer" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Foreground="White" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Main menu" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" Foreground="White" />
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" Background="White">
        <TextBox Height="78" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,16,0,0" Name="TextBox1" Text="Please select one of the following:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF00B1FF" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" />
        <Button Content="Hex Date" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="81,88,0,0" Name="btnHex" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275" Foreground="#FF00B1FF" BorderBrush="#FF00B1FF" />
        <Button Content="Julian Date" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="81,196,0,0" Name="btnJulian" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275" BorderBrush="#FF00B1FF" Foreground="#FF00B1FF" />
        <Button Content="Reverse Julian Date" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="81,304,0,0" Name="btnReverseJulian" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275" Foreground="#FF00B1FF" BorderBrush="#FF00B1FF" />
        <Button BorderBrush="#FF00B1FF" Content="Callout Form" Foreground="#FF00B1FF" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="81,412,0,0" Name="btnCalloutform" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275" />
        <Image Height="76" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,511,0,0" Name="Image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" Source="/RSG%20Engineer;component/Images/k3_rsg_rgb_Small.png" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>

<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>



<!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

Comment: Odds are your resource uri is wrong, but it's hard to tell without seeing any code.  Can you post your current code?  (And maybe a screenshot of your project structure)

Comment: Which code did you need? the XML or the vb.net code?

Comment: anything/everything that could be relevant.

Comment: i can't all my code because it is too long, but the image XML is:
<Image Height="76" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,511,0,0" Name="Image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" Source="/RSG%20Engineer;component/Images/k3_rsg_rgb_Small.png" />

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry about that, i have done now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click Images folder and click Add >> Existing Item
Browse to the correct location and find the file. Click okay and the file is imported in the project.

Lets look at the properties of the imported file. Default build action is set to Resource. Lets now add Image control and display the image.

```
<Image Source=”/PhoneApp1;component/Images/k3_rsg_rgb_Small.png” />
```

As you can see its a slightly complicated path though there’s nothing wrong with it. It works just fine. Now lets try setting the image BuildAction to Content. When setting it to content, please remember to set “Copy to Output Folder to “Copy Always”. Now we need to modify the XAML

```
<Image Source=”/Images/k3_rsg_rgb_Small.png” />
```

Can view original post at: 
http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2011/09/30/images-and-build-actio-settings-in-wp7/

Comment: I have tried this and it is not showing the image as it should

Comment: Oh i am sorry i misread your answer and didn't change the XAML as i should've and it is now working. Thank you :)